# Not using `where` clause, but getting error:"unknown column <col_name> in where clause"

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause

I've already searched many SO answer with same title. Pls help me out before marking it as duplicate.

I'm getting a strange error in `MySQL` query.

Below is the description of table.

[image: desc snap of table]

I'm trying to insert values in a table with the following queries

```
INSERT INTO `UL`.`B_FHCL_IOT_MACHINEDATA`(`STATUS`, `MACHINE_ID`, `PRODUCT_ID`, `MACHINE_ITEM_COUNT`, `OPENING_READING`, `CLOSING_READING`, `CONSUMPTION`,
                    `TRANSACTION_DATE`, `CUR_DATE`, `TRANSACTION_TIME`, `CUR_TIME`, `MACHINE_DAYCOUNTER`, `SOURCE`)
                    VALUES('active','9','5',230,'211','230','19','2018-03-02','2018-03-02','09:20','09:20',568,'auto');
```

But getting error message as

```
12:18:43    INSERT INTO `UL`.`B_FHCL_IOT_MACHINEDATA`(`STATUS`, `MACHINE_ID`, `PRODUCT_ID`, `MACHINE_ITEM_COUNT`, `OPENING_READING`, `CLOSING_READING`, `CONSUMPTION`,      `TRANSACTION_DATE`, `CUR_DATE`, `TRANSACTION_TIME`, `CUR_TIME`, `MACHINE_DAYCOUNTER`, `SOURCE`)      VALUES('active','9','5',230,'211','230','19','2018-03-02','2018-03-02','09:20','09:20',568,'auto') Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'MACHINE_ID' in 'where clause' 0.234 sec
```

**There is no `where` clause in the above `insert` statement**

I've tried without backticks too.

Not able to understand, why the error is occurring only on 2nd column `MACHINE_ID`.

All columns specified in the statement, are available in the table.

Pls someone help me out here, what mistake I'm doing here.

Comment: MACHINE_ID column is not in your table

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest doing a "describe B_FHCL_IOT_MACHINEDATA" to verify the table fields...

Comment: I've added a snap of table description. pls check.

Comment: Have you others sql commands before this .in your scripts? .. check if you missing some end statements as ;

Comment: The `insert` statement is having ; at the end.

Comment: @RajaRamachandran the column is available in the table.

Comment: Is there a trigger on this table?

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes, it was there. You're the rockstar my friend. Saved my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @P.Salmon Pls make your suggestion as an answer on this question, which can help another people who doesn't think these stuff like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I was bit careless. If the people like me, is really getting this type of strange issue.

Please don't be panic here.

As P.Salmon has guessed. The trigger was running `after insert` on the table.
And basically, this trigger was throwing the error.

As I dropped the trigger, the query worked perfectly.